Target a specific cell not a rows
I have this code working for me, but It is locked to columns and I need it for a specific cell. is this possible? and if I enter only 6 digits into a cell, can I get excel to just add a 0 at the end?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ThisColumn = Target.Column
    If ThisColumn < 3 Then
        UserInput = Target.Value
        If UserInput > 1 Then
            NewInput = Left(UserInput, 2) & ":" & Mid(UserInput, 3, 2) & "," & Mid(UserInput, 5, 3)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = NewInput
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub


I tried searching around for how to use vba to target a specific cell, but I'm not that smart and couldn't really understand what I was reading. Mostly I just got the macro to stop working


if I enter only 6 digits into a cell suppose it is a number without decimal point.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UserInput, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$B$2:D10"  ' modify as needed
    Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(CELL_ADDRESS))
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each c in Rng.Cells
        UserInput = c.Value
        If Len(UserInput) = 6 And IsNumeric(UserInput) Then
            c.Value = UserInput * 10
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


so the small changes for Const Cell_adress works great. to change my code to a specific cell but I can't seem to get the rest of your adding a 0 to work together with  my code..

A number with 6 digits (excluding the decimal point) is an integer. Multiplying it by 10 adds a zero to the end. For example, converting 123456 to 1234560.

Okay. and if I wanted it to work in multiple cells? seperate results for seperate cells

I've updated the code.

A Worksheet Change: Modify Changed Cell

If the user manually enters a value in cell A2 (TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS) of the worksheet containing this code, the input is modified in the following way:

If the user entered 7 digits, e.g. 1234567, it will replace them with 12:34,567.
If the user entered 6 digits, e.g. 123456, it will replace them with 12:34,560 (related to LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_CHAR, LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_COUNT).
If the cell value was cleared it remains cleared.
In any other case, the input is replaced with INVALID_OLD_STRING_REPLACEMENT (currently cleared).
If LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_COUNT were set to 2, it would also replace e.g. 12345 with 12:34,500.



Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1

In Excel, right-click the correct sheet tab and select View Code. Copy the following code into the just opened window in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE). Close VBE.
The code runs automatically (there's nothing to run). Simply start typing in the given cell (currently A2) and observe what happens after pressing Enter.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_CHAR As String = "0"
    Const LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_COUNT As Long = 1 ' '< NewLen'
    Const INVALID_OLD_STRING_REPLACEMENT As String = ""
    ' The following 3 arrays must have the same number of elements.
    Dim DELIMITERS() As Variant: DELIMITERS = VBA.Array("", ":", ",")
    Dim NEW_STARTS() As Variant: NEW_STARTS = VBA.Array(1, 3, 5)
    Dim NEW_LENGTHS() As Variant: NEW_LENGTHS = VBA.Array(2, 2, 3)
    
    ' Check if cell has not changed.
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = Me.Range(TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS)
    If Intersect(tcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' cell not changed
    
    ' Retrieve old string and check if its length is zero (blank).
    Dim OldString As String: OldString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    Dim OldLen As Long: OldLen = Len(OldString)
    If OldLen = 0 Then Exit Sub ' cell is blank
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim n As Long, NewString As String, IsOldStringValid As Boolean
    
    ' Validate old string.
    Dim NewLen As Long: NewLen = Application.Sum(NEW_LENGTHS)
    Select Case OldLen
        Case NewLen - LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_COUNT To NewLen ' 6 or 7
            If OldString Like String(OldLen, "#") Then IsOldStringValid = True
    End Select
    
    ' Build new string.
    If IsOldStringValid Then
        ' Build valid old string (add missing digit if applicable).
        OldString = OldString & String(NewLen - OldLen, LAST_MISSING_DIGITS_CHAR)
        ' Build new string.
        For n = 0 To UBound(NEW_STARTS)
            NewString = NewString & DELIMITERS(n) _
                & Mid(OldString, NEW_STARTS(n), NEW_LENGTHS(n))
        Next n
    Else ' old string is invalid
        NewString = INVALID_OLD_STRING_REPLACEMENT
    End If
    
    ' Replace old with new string.
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' prevent retriggering this code
        tcell.Value = NewString
    Application.EnableEvents = True
        
End Sub


waow.. my small code suddenly became a big one :D

Follow up question.. If I want this to work in multiple cells.. separably of-coarse.. I need it working in 8 different cells.. I'm used to when working with all this coding in VBA it starts with a IF and ends with and End If  and I can always just copy past the code and add the new cell adress in the next one.. but not here
